# How to create Proof of Stake node?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, private-blockchain, proof-of-stake, proof-of-work

I need to create a Proof of Stake node Ethereum but I'm not be able to find the solution.

I know how to create PoA and PoW networks but have no idea about PoS.

e.g **to create a PoA network** we need to define the **clique in the genesis.json file**
for **PoW** we need to define the **eth hash**
but for PoS what do we need to pass in the genesis file or any other way?

Can someone please guide me to create a PoS node?

I want to create Ethereum private node using a proof of concept

Comment: Do you mean Proof of Stake?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a Proof of Stake node

Comment: What does PoA mean?

Comment: Before Ethereum2.O, there was PoW(Proof of Work) and PoA(Proof of Authority). After that they have introduced new consenses PoS(Proof of Stake)